# NodeJS browser session

Tags: node.js, express

I'm quite new to NodeJS so could someone explain this to me:

I've got a simple authorization on my endpoint created in express. As you can see in the code there is no JWT or session cookie set anywhere. I've also checked in browses cookies just to be sure and there is no sessionId set anywhere.
With that in mind I'd expect my app to prompt for credentials each time I refresh the page ( or at least when I manually delete all cookies, refresh cache and then refresh the page) but that's not happening. Browser is still sending request with correct authorization header (after i put credentials for the first time and refresh page) and I have no idea why.

simple endpoint code:

```
app.get('/cms', function (req, res) {

    const reject = () => {
        res.setHeader("www-authenticate", "Basic");
        res.sendStatus(401);
    };
    const authorization = req.headers.authorization;

    if (!authorization) {
        return reject();
    }
    const [username, password] = Buffer.from(
        authorization.replace("Basic ", ""),
        "base64"
    )
        .toString()
        .split(":");

    if (!(username === "user" && password === "pass")) {
        return reject();
    }
    res.status(200)
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/cms.html'));
});
```

Comment: Hi, could you provide more information about the client/front-end side ? How the authentication is handled, do you use any library, framework, etc.. The credentials send in the authorization header must be save somewhere ^^ If not the cookies, maybe in local storage, session storage or anything else ... Can you also provide the middlewares, if any, in use with nodejs /express ?

Comment: The app is ass simple as it gets, there is nothing on the frontend side - the only way to acces it is to manualy type the url addres in browser. No middleware as well, thats  almost the entire code. The only libs used are express, path and mongoose.

Comment: I clearly miss something ... How do you set the authorization header with just plain url in the browser' search bar ?

Comment: Its a re-request sent by client browser as explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization  It prompts or user and password ( default browser one)

Comment: Oh gosh ! It is the [www-authenticate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate) in the response header that causes the browser to request and prompt authentication. I'm learning every day, I've never used this. It seems browser specific, the credentials will be saved somewhere at their own discretion and send back in the authorization header on each request. For example, in this [article](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/web/FirefoxLogoutBasicAuth?showcomments). It is not Nodejs specific

Comment: Tested on 4 browsers  chrome, Opera, firefox,edge.

Comment: Yup, each browser should have its own implementation, storing the credential somewhere in its memory and setting the authorization header on each request. Browsers don't seem to provide an API to interact with them, we have no control over the credential :/ But for a "simple" authentication mechanism, it seems nice and efficient. The thing is, the "magic" happens in our browsers, Nodejs and express are not responisble for this mechanism.